# Vite server proxy does not return the full path

Tags: vite

I am in the process of migrating a webapp from Webpack to Vite, and ran into an issue with its server proxy:

I have a rather long url with query parameters, where I'd like my devServer to rewrite a part of it:

```
'/signin-oidc.asp': {
  target: 'https://identity.myIdentity.etc/',
  rewrite: path =>
      path.replace(
        '/signin-oidc.asp?',
        '/tm/signin?origHost=localhost:3100&origPath=/signin-oidc.asp&origSecure=0&'
      ),
  secure: false,
  changeOrigin: true,
},
```

The problem is, while webpack's pathRewrite returned the entire URL, in Vite, the only thing that comes back on the rewrite path parameter is `'/signin-oidc.asp'` which makes retaining query params in the rewritten URL impossible.

I expected Vite's rewrite to return the entire URL in the callback parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a different plugin is killing the rewrite:
https://github.com/vbenjs/vite-plugin-html/pull/96